# Shutdown resets my steam downloads

Tags: steam

Whenever I download a game and before it's finished, if I shutdown my computer, the download gets reset and I have to download the whole thing again.

Can someone tell me why this is happening and if there is a workaround for it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because the partial-game is being downloaded into cache, and upon completion, its moved onto your system.

When you restart your PC, cache and temp files are cleared, thus losing the games download progress.

**EDIT:** Im not sure if there is a workaround, if there is, I wouldnt be familiar with it.

**EDIT2** Try this

Load Steam

From the Library section, 
right-click on the game and select Properties from the menu.
Select the Local files tab and click the Verify integrity of game cache... button.

Comment: I don't believe this is 100% accurate - I have Metro 2033 downloading via Steam (about 2 GB left to go) and when I shut down and restarted my PC, the download resumed right where I left off.

Comment: Where is the partial game being stored? does your cache clear when you restart?

Comment: I haven't changed any of that, and I don't know that it is possible to do so via Steam.  I would expect that a good answer to this question would explain these mechanics :)

Comment: it probably is saved in the %TEMP% folder which may or may not be cleared depending on cumputer settings

Comment: Actually, the method Ron posted worked.....

Comment: Isn't pausing the download an option? I've got like 10 game downloads paused. And if i continue them they still keep going from where i stopped.

Comment: Ron's answer did not work for me. My downloads still restart after shutdown. Help please :(

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I got it to work.

1.) Locate the folder of the game you are trying to install that got reset, if it's not there, let the game download re-download like maybe 50mbs or so, and it should show up.

2.) Go onto Program Files/Steam/Steamapps/downloading and you will see a bunch of files in there that were left from the download that stopped. If you are dling more than 1 game at once you may have to sort through them, if not, take all of those files and move them onto the corresponding game folder.

3.) Go onto your library and verify the integrity of that games cache, then start the download again and it should go back up to where you left off.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The patch files?
And the isn't the game folder insid ethe downloading folder? So I copy them into that?

Answer (score -3):

i think it's because we installed steam in the windows directory but the library is in another place

Comment: That's just stupid, why would that reset downloads? Downvote from me, sorry.